# C# Deserialize Json string from Quandl

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, quandl

I have spent a few hours on this and still can't find the answer. I have a Json string I need to deserialize. It should be simple but I get the following error message:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: Q. Path '', line 0, position 0.

My json string is the following:

https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/GDP.json?auth_token=Mi1xP1q2776TU4kmGcHo&collapse=monthly&transformation=none&sort_order=asc&rows=100

It is a link to a Json string provided by the Quandl online database.

I used the following website:

http://json2csharp.com/

to generate the necessary class.

I understand I then to have to deserialize into this class using:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(request.jsonString);
```

but it is not working.

Here is my full code:

```
    public class Errors
    {
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Errors errors { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string source_name { get; set; }
        public string source_code { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string urlize_name { get; set; }
        public string display_url { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public string frequency { get; set; }
        public string from_date { get; set; }
        public string to_date { get; set; }
        public List<string> column_names { get; set; }
        public bool @private { get; set; }
        public object type { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
    }
    private void PullFromQuandl()
    {
        QuandlDownloadRequest request = new QuandlDownloadRequest();
        request.APIKey = "Mi1xP1q2776TU4kmGcHo";
        request.Datacode = new Datacode("FRED", "GDP");
        request.Format = FileFormats.JSON;
        request.Frequency = Frequencies.Monthly;
        request.Truncation = 100;
        request.Sort = SortOrders.Ascending;

        string jsonString = request.ToRequestString();

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>> (jsonString);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark this as an answer, because what you posted as an answer could be done much more easily from a look at the quandl api:

```
using QuandlCS.Connection; // need to use this
```

and then

```
QuandlConnection conn = new QuandlConnection ();
string json = conn.Request(request); // request is your QuandlDownloadRequst
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

that is the same as in you answer. they have a class for that :D

for further reference look at their C# api docs: https://github.com/HubertJ/QuandlCS

Comment: Well played sir. A lot simpler. Any idea how I then bind that object to a datagridview?

Comment: dgvPending.Datasource = obj;

Comment: datasource must be a Collection type (List etc). You can try dgv.DataSource = obj.data. but im pretty sure it wont work. so either iterate manually over obj.data and use `dgvPending.Rows.Add()` or somehow make a proper`List<SomeClass>` out of the `data` array (manually) and then put that as DataSource

Comment: I will just iterate manually with dgvPending.Rows.Add(). Seems simpler. But how do I extract a row? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `foreach(List<object> item in obj.data) { dgv.Rows.Add(item[0],item[1]); }` would be a good way to start

Comment: Tried that, but keeps throwing up an error message. Will keep trying.

Comment: I got it working. Thank you x4rf41. You really helped. Is there any other way I can upvote you? I would send you money if I could, no joke. This basically means I can display any dataset from Quandl straight into the application (exchange rates, GDP figures etc). My boss will be happy. Thanks for taking the time. the code was:             dgvPending.Columns.Add("Name", "Date");
            dgvPending.Columns.Add("Name", "Rate");
            foreach (List<object> item in obj.data) { dgvPending.Rows.Add(item[0], item[1]); }

Comment: its fine man, im basically getting paid for this because im at work and got nothing better to do :D

Comment: Haha and I am working overtime without getting paid. So I guess it goes full circle. Cheers, keep it up. I hope to be as good as you someday.

Answer (score 0):

The string is indeed a json string. Thanks for the link you provided. 
I made a silly mistake. Quandl was returning the link to the string.
So I used HttpWebRequest to obtain the string itself. 
I then edited the deserialization as you suggest. 
I think it worked. The problem now is that it is not binding to my datagridview.

```
        private void PullFromQuandl()
       {
        QuandlDownloadRequest request = new QuandlDownloadRequest();
        request.APIKey = "Mi1xP1q2776TU4kmGcHo";
        request.Datacode = new Datacode("CURRFX", "EURUSD");
        request.Format = FileFormats.JSON;
        request.Frequency = Frequencies.Monthly;
        request.Truncation = 100;
        request.Sort = SortOrders.Ascending;
        string jsonString = request.ToRequestString();

        HttpWebRequest request2 = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        string returnData = string.Empty;
        request2 = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(jsonString));
        request2.Method = "GET";
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        returnData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(returnData);
        dgvPending.DataSource = result;
        }
```

Comment: look at the answer i just posted, you could have done that much more easily :D

Answer (score -1):

First of all: Avoid object type. JSON Serializers -> Deserializers usually have problems with it.

Second:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>> (jsonString);
```

you are trying to deserialize an array of RootObject. but the provided json only contains one. it should be:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (jsonString);
```

Third:

```
string jsonString = request.ToRequestString();
```

can you debug and look if `jsonString` actually contains valid json (use http://jsonlint.org/). Seems to me you would need a **response** string and not a request string. **(I think that is why you get the error!!!)**

Fourth:

there will probably be more errors. I kinda doubt that a json deserializer with default settings will be able to decode the data array properly. but `List<List<object>>` is worth a try. if it gives an error try `List<List<string>>` instead. if that doesnt work you will probably have to do it manually.

**Check the json with a debugger please**. i think what you are trying to deserialize is NOT what you posted here!

also: from what library do you use this: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`?

Fifth:

who the **** designed their api to produce that kind of json:

```
[
        [
            "1947-01-31",
            243.1
        ]
]
```

that is just plain and simple retarded (i just had to say it)

Comment: but i was right that your jsonString was incorrect?

Comment: Or at least, I think I did. I will post the code now.

Comment: i looked at the api class and the `ToRequestString` just returns the url you need for the api call. you still have to actually do the api call

Comment: I am using the Newtonsoft.Json libray and QuandlCS API.